# How to extend IconNodeWidget class in java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I should make a GUI that uses Visual Library. I have a scene where users can put nodes and edit some propierties. Then I want to save each node propierties. For that i'm trying to extend IconNodeWidget class to add some members to the nodes (let's call them X and Y). When user select a node and choose edit propierties i should show that values. 
 The problem is that i can't extend IconNodeWidget class.
How can i make this?

Comment: Are you referring to the NetBeans Visual Library? Can you add a link?

Comment: Excuse, i forgot to say that. Yes i'm using NetBeans Visual Library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of the GUI library you're using, but I'd recommend considering a MVC pattern.

Widget properties (aka model) would be stored in an separate tree, and the view would be Visual Library objects.